# Bitnami mongodb cluster con't access from mongo3t client kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, bitnami

I have installed bitnami mongodb cluster with `helm install my-release bitnami/mongodb -f values-production.yaml .` , `architecture: replicaset , and replicaCount: 2` in aws server,

```
helm version version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.2.4",CHART mongodb-8.2.1, APP VERSION 4.2.8,  kubectl version GitVersion:"v1.16.8"
```

Its installed successfully one statefulset along with three pods and one svc , I have put port forward, to get  access mongodb from roto3T client as a localhost with using user name and password , But its getting Error , it is `Authorization failed on admin database as root`

I have tryed with portforword to svc , pod, and statefulset all are getting same error .

```
kubectl port-forward  --namespace default svc/my-release-mongodb-headless 27017:27017
```

Is it I done any wrong or anything extra i need to mension in values-production.yaml file ?

Comment: Can you exec into pod and execute following command: `mongo admin --host "mongo-mongodb-0.mongo-mongodb-headless.default.svc.cluster.local,mongo-mongodb-1.mongo-mongodb-headless.default.svc.cluster.local," --authenticationDatabase admin -u root -p $MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD` ? Are there any issues when you are not using roto3T?

Comment: I can go inside using exec and login into mongodb, it is working , only getting issue , when i create `port-forward` and access though Robo3T as a localhost , Robo3T is mongodb client , any solution ? , normaly all db we can access though port-forwed why not bitnami-mongo cluster?

Comment: Bitnami developer here. I see you asked here: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/3751 Added my comments there. I was unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @JavierSalmeron can u plz share me the host name which one used in mongo3T and  portforward command ? , i need to know  where you portforward , becoase its not happening from myside

Comment: I have removed and installed once , but its getting same error .
This is my values-production.yaml file, 
https://github.com/SHUFIL/bitnami-mongo-cluster/blob/master/values-production.yaml

Comment: I used localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will install and working fine with below cammand

```
helm install mongo-cluster-name . -f values-production.yaml --set architecture=replicaset --set replicaCount=2
```

this will start statefulset and svc and pod along with disk, if we do the portforward to svc name mongo-cluster-name-headless, we can access as a localhost

```
kubectl port-forward --namespace default svc/mmongo-cluster-name-headless 27017:27017
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, probable because svc/mmongo-cluster-name-headless has no ClusterIP IP. It's written None !! It's not a service like it is when you are doing a standalone

Comment: yes its seems cluster ip None , but we can do port-forward and can able to connect DB from other service as well
@JavierSalmeron.. will give more details better that me

Answer (score 0):

you can't do a port-forward in a replicaset architecture.

https://docs.mongodb.com/kubernetes-operator/master/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/#enable-external-access-for-a-replica-set

You are using helm ? nice just check this lines there is an option just made for you https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/mongodb/values.yaml#L446

This is gonna create a LoadBalancer for each of you primary & secondary mongodb pods.

But LoadBalancer are quite expensive (it's kind of 15 euros/month for me), so 30/month just to access the replicaset (2 replicas mini) from outside.